# drop function in haskell - implementation with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

Look at my drop function. It is working indeed. It is lazy - works for infinite lists.

```
drop3 :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop3 n xs = [x | (x, y) <- zip xs [1..], y > n]
```

I think is there differe way else to write it using list comprehension.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not taking the "usual" recursive definition, instead of a list comprehension? Just because you can? ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that list comprehensions can have traps. For example, suppose you try to define `take` in that same way: `take n xs = [x | (x, y) <- zip xs [1..], y <= n]`. If you test this on an infinite list you see that things don't really go well.

Comment: Unlike the usual recursive approach, this *copies* the list. Quite inefficient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are asking about the usual *recursive* approach:

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' _ [] = []
drop' n xs@(_:xs')
   | n > 0     = drop' (n-1) xs'
   | otherwise = xs
```

note that this will silently accept *negative* drops and *to-much* drops like

- `drop' (-1) [1..4] = [1,2,3,4]`
- `drop' 10 [1..4]   = []`